# Global Variable not carrying over- Javascript FCF

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase cloud functions in which I define a variable commentIdSpecific. When I log it inside the function: -- `console.log(comm id ${commentIdSpecific});` -- it prints its value. When I try to print it here: -- `console.log(test of variables inisde of post: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}, uwotpi: ${commentIdSpecific})` -- it returns undefined. I've looked at three websites talking about global vars and it doesn't seem any different from what I have here.

How do I go about getting the value in the second print statement to be in the first? Thanks in advance.

```
var commentIdSpecific;
  db.ref(`/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments`).once('value').then(snap => {
      commentIdSpecific = snap.val();
      let ids = [];
         for (var id in snap.val()) {
           ids.push(id);
         }
  let lastValueId = ids[ids.length - 1]
  console.log(`last id value ${lastValueId}. UserPost: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}. user owner post id: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}...`);
  commentIdSpecific = lastValueId;
  console.log(`comm id ${commentIdSpecific}`);
      return commentIdSpecific;
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });


  var commentPoster;
  db.ref(`/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments/${commentIdSpecific}/comment`).once('value').then(snap => {
      commentPoster = snap.val();
      console.log(`commentPoster: ${snap.val()}`);
      console.log(`test of variables inisde of post: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}, uwotpi: ${commentIdSpecific}`)
      return commentPoster
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`once()` is asynchronous and returns immediately with a promise that indicates when the async work is complete.  Likewise, `then()` returns immediately with a promise.  The callback you pass to `then()` is executed some unknown amount of time later, whenever the results of the query are finished.  Until that happens, your code keeps executing at the next line, which means `commentIdSpecific` will be undefined when it's first accessed.

You need to use a promise chain to make sure the work that depends on the results of async work is only accessed after it becomes available.

You may want to watch the videos on JavaScript promises on this page in order to better learn how they're used in Cloud Functions.  It's absolutely critical to understand how they work to write effective code.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I watched your sequential and parallel work in js, but you were returning the array of promises(at around 4:40), and I couldn't return just my commentIdSpecific like this: return Promise.all(commentIdSpecific); Sorry, I'm sort of new with js and Firebase functions although I really liked your video.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the second `db.ref` call in promise chain once the first promise resolved like this:

```
  db.ref(`/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments`).once('value')
.then(snap => {
      commentIdSpecific = snap.val();
      let ids = [];
         for (var id in snap.val()) {
           ids.push(id);
         }
  let lastValueId = ids[ids.length - 1]
  console.log(`last id value ${lastValueId}. UserPost: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}. user owner post id: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}...`);
  commentIdSpecific = lastValueId;
  console.log(`comm id ${commentIdSpecific}`);
      return commentIdSpecific;
    })
.then(commentIdSpecific => {
db.ref(`/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments/${commentIdSpecific}/comment`).once('value').then(snap => {
      commentPoster = snap.val();
      console.log(`commentPoster: ${snap.val()}`);
      console.log(`test of variables inisde of post: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}, uwotpi: ${commentIdSpecific}`)
      return commentPoster
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

`once()` is an async operation so it might possible that `console.log(test of variables inside of post: ${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}, uwotpi: ${commentIdSpecific})`  executed before `commentIdSpecific = snap.val();` and `commentIdSpecific = lastValueId;`

So what you need to do is first let `db.ref(/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments)` be completed and then make call to `db.ref(/users/${usernameWhoOwnsThePost}/posts/${usernameWhoOwnsThePostID}/comments/${commentIdSpecific}/comment)` in next `.then()` in the chain.

As you are returning `commentIdSpecific` form first `.then()` So it will be available as param in second `.then()`.

https://javascript.info/promise-chaining will help you to dig `.then chaining` more into deep.

Comment: Thanks for the response @samee ,when I copied and pasted your code in I got this error: 147:9  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  148:3  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  148:3  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting

Comment: How do you avoid nesting promises?